# how to find the coordinates of an autoresizemasked object after rotation

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview

[image]Hi,

can we find the coordinates of a UI element say UItextfield which is masked after rotation, if yes how is it possible?

Thanx in advance

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I understand your question. If you want to know the coordinates of a UI element after your device was rotated, here's how you do it:

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
     CGRect newFrame = someUIElement.frame;
     int x = newFrame.origin.x;     // x-Coordinate
     int y = newFrame.origin.y;     // y-Coordinate
     // do stuff with coordinates
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have something like fabian answer while rotating the device first called method is `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}`
 then -(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration

finally

-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
 method called so you can get the coordinates in this method.The main thing here is the object origin ll change not the size.this is the thing i am expecting from some sample app.